# how to create dataframe columns with computation using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Instead of

```
cv['Open1'] = cv['Open'].pct_change(fill_method=None)
cv['Open2'] = cv['Open'].pct_change(periods=2,fill_method=None)
cv['Open3'] = cv['Open'].pct_change(periods=3,fill_method=None)
cv['Open4'] = cv['Open'].pct_change(periods=4,fill_method=None)
cv['Open5'] = cv['Open'].pct_change(periods=5,fill_method=None)
```

I tried to do

```
for i in range(0, 4, 1):
    Open_values += cv['Open%d' % (i) .pct_change(periods='%d' %(i)]
    Open_names += ["Open%d" % (i)]
cv = pd.concat([Open_values],names=['Open_names'])
```

but it doesnt work.

my desired output is:

| Open1 | Open2 | Open3 | Open4 | Open5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| #.## | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| #.## | #.## | nan | nan | nan |
| #.## | #.## | #.## | nan | nan |
| #.## | #.## | #.## | #.## | nan |
| #.## | #.## | #.## | #.## | #.## |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to create the name of the column or concatenate separately, also the index of the range was off by 1.

```
for i in range(1, 6, 1):
    cv['Open%d'%(i)] = cv['Open'].pct_change(periods=i,fill_method=None)
```